# How to split Pandas Frame base on number switch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to split a pandas dataframe base on number switch from 4.2 to 4.19 in one column.

I cannot use the diff() method as the difference (0.01) also occurs when in the diff column when the data changes from 4.19 to 4.18. Moreso splitting base on a particular number (e.g 4.2 or 4.19) does not work as the column has multiples of these numbers (e.g 4.2 appears like 5 times).

The data looks like this

4.1999
4.1999
4.2
4.1999
4.1975
4.2
4.19
4.1931
4.192
4.1911
4.1902
4.1896
4.189
4.1883

Is there a way to split such dataframe when the numbers change from 4.2 to 4.19 using pandas or any other python method?

Thank you very much in advance.

Sincerely,

Cindino

Answer (score 0):

Use shift to construct your mask with split points:

```
split_points = df.column.eq(4.2) & df.column.shift(-1).eq(4.19)
```

Or:

```
split_points = df.column.shift(1).eq(4.2) & df.column.eq(4.19)
```

Depending on where you want the split to occur

Example of use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [4.1999,4.1999,4.2,4.1999,4.1975,4.2,4.19,4.1931,4.192,4.1911,4.1902,4.1896,4.189,4.1883]})
df['split'] = df['col'].shift(1).eq(4.2) & df['col'].eq(4.19)
df['group'] = df['split'].cumsum()
df
```

output:

```
       col  split  group
0   4.1999  False      0
1   4.1999  False      0
2   4.2000  False      0
3   4.1999  False      0
4   4.1975  False      0
5   4.2000  False      0
6   4.1900   True      1
7   4.1931  False      1
8   4.1920  False      1
9   4.1911  False      1
10  4.1902  False      1
11  4.1896  False      1
12  4.1890  False      1
13  4.1883  False      1
```

You can then access the subframes using `groupby`:

```
list(df.groupby('group'))
```

```
[(0,
        col  split  group
  0  4.1999  False      0
  1  4.1999  False      0
  2  4.2000  False      0
  3  4.1999  False      0
  4  4.1975  False      0
  5  4.2000  False      0),
 (1,
         col  split  group
  6   4.1900   True      1
  7   4.1931  False      1
  8   4.1920  False      1
  9   4.1911  False      1
  10  4.1902  False      1
  11  4.1896  False      1
  12  4.1890  False      1
  13  4.1883  False      1)]
```

Or directly:

```
list(df.groupby((df['col'].shift(1).eq(4.2) & df['col'].eq(4.19)).cumsum()))
```

output:

```
[(0,
        col
  0  4.1999
  1  4.1999
  2  4.2000
  3  4.1999
  4  4.1975
  5  4.2000),
 (1,
         col
  6   4.1900
  7   4.1931
  8   4.1920
  9   4.1911
  10  4.1902
  11  4.1896
  12  4.1890
  13  4.1883)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reponse. I tried this and got a series filled with the boolen 'False' . I guess if the condition was met, I will have a true in it but that is not the case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited the question and added a sample data to better illustrate the problem. I also tried the second method and got a series with only false

Comment: I provided an example myself ;)

Comment: Did it solve your question with the real case dataset?

Comment: One more thing. will it be possible to interate this. The data seems to have another switch point. In this case, the code can interate it continuously whenever this change occurs (4.2 to 4.19) so i can have a column with 0 when the value is increasing from 3 to 4.2 (switch 3 to 3.1) and 1 when the value is decreasing from 4.2 to 3 (switch 4.2 to 4.19)

Comment: My code is already doing that, it will produce n+1 sub-dfs for n split points. To iterate over the sub-dfs, do: `for subdf_id, subdf in df.groupby(...): ...`

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly, I just see your split condition is varying. This is doable, I'll update the answer later.